# Is this a good polariser and is it for an appropriate price?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, filters, polarizer, pricing, hoya

I'm thinking about purchasing [Hoya HD 58mm Circular Polariser](http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/Hoya-HD-58mm-Circular-Polarizing-Polariser-Filter-CPL-/260776123497?pt=UK_CamerasPhoto_CameraAccessories_CameraLensesFilters_JN&hash=item3cb777dc69) and I was wondering whether it's a good choice and also whether it's for an appropriate price. What do you guys think?

Comment: eBay links always end up dead in a few months it seems. Maybe list the important info from the link here, and link to the mfg site? I think price is the only thing missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes, this is an excellent polarizer.** Probably the best there is and certainly the best one I own. I paid much more than that for the 77mm.

Hoya HD polarizers let about 1 stop more light pass through than normal or multi-coated ones. This is a tremendous advantage.

Comment: What about the price? Is it overpriced, or is it a good price?

Comment: Looks like a really good price to me (based on today's exchange rate).

Comment: If anything, it might be too cheap

Comment: @Rowland Shaw Meaning its a fake?

Comment: @fmark I cannot tell if it is a fake or not just from an eBay listing; in the same way that I couldn't tell if a battery was. I'd normally refer to http://www.camerapricebuster.co.uk/hoyafilters.html for finding a realistic street price, but they don't list the HD variants; Amazon has it about the same price though http://www.amazon.co.uk/HOYA-HD-POLFILTER-CIRCULAR-58/dp/B001GJ33V2/ref=pd_sim_ce_9

Answer (score 0):

I use the site [Lenstip.com Polarizing filters test](http://www.lenstip.com/115.1-article-Polarizing_filters_test.html)  to understand performance on filters (UV and Polarizing).  Their analysis of the real-world performance of filters is reliable and repeatable.  I like that they provide an extensive lineup of comparable products.

I didn't see the exact model of the one that you reference, but the Hoya filters do rate highly.